How can I check Neywork Discovery status without knowing the computer language?
I'm currently devemopping a bunch of scripts to test if some of our company softwareq can be installed on a computer or not. The aim is to launch our programm and it will generate a report saying what is missing in your configuration.
One test I'm having trouble with is checking if Network discovery is enabled.
Currently, our script do something like this to test it :
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Network Discovery' -Enabled True
This was working during our development. But after some other tests, we discovered that this command answer is language specific. So if the script is launched on a computer with French as first language, nothing comes out as "Network Discovery" in DisplayGroup is now "Découverte de réseaux"...
I need this script to work in many different countries and can't test every possible language, so how can I achieve that ?

Is the Group member independent of localization? Get-NetFirewallRule -Group '@FirewallAPI.dll,-32752' -Enabled True

That seem to work. I thought it wouldn't, but it's a mistranslation on my side, as the french version in not the one I expected. So Thanks !

Lit found the answer, rather than using DisplayGroup to discriminate, I can use Group, which does not depend of local language.
